# What are differences between quantitative analyst and data scientist in IT companies?

Tags: job-description

What are differences between quantitative analyst  and data scientist  in IT companies? Both seem to deal with data, requiring statistics and programming.

Comment: This seems too subjective to be on topic.  A title means whatever the company intends it to mean.  Some companies may use one title.  Other companies may use another for the same type of position.  Other companies may use the titles completely differently.

Comment: Is this a some wide-known title or it's bound to a specific company? If later, then no one can reply to this since each company can name some role as it wants. I had the same confusions when I tried to figure our what developer's level exist - the answer is that there are thousands of variations.

Comment: One difference is that data scientist is a hype-word...

Comment: @wpb: Yes, the two are  wide-known titles, in IT companies, such as Google, Facebook, etc

Comment: Hi Tom, just a suggestion for your questions to prevent them from getting put on hold, focus on providing plenty of detail. If your motivation for asking is to solve a particular problem, be sure to explain how the answers to the question will help you. This gives the question some context and helps ensure they can be answered with facts, references, and specific expertise, which will also make the posts helpful to future visitors coming here from Google. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @Tom That's even better since such large companies will definitely have position scope document which you can probably easily find on the net. But even thou, do not be so sure just because large companies are using it. As I told you, the more people you have, the more specific qualifications you seek. And then you come upon specific positions. So you either try Wikipedia or search for Google, Facebook vacancies. That's how I try to find description of some IT position and succeed all the time.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia on Quantitative Analyst](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantitative_analyst), which isn't necessarily what you meant I think:

> A quantitative analyst is a person who works in finance using
>   numerical or quantitative techniques. Similar work is done in most
>   other modern industries, but the work is not always called
>   quantitative analysis. In the investment industry, people who perform
>   quantitative analysis are frequently called quants.

Thus, these are people that would fall under the **Finance** department.

[IBM on Data Scientist](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/infosphere/data-scientist/):

> Rising alongside the relatively new technology of big data is the new
>   job title data scientist. While not tied exclusively to big data
>   projects, the data scientist role does complement them because of the
>   increased breadth and depth of data being examined, as compared to
>   traditional roles.

In this case, I would think the term is still relatively new, as Wikipedia does have an article on ["Data Science"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_science) which notes a practitioner to be a data scientist with a link to redirect back to the article on "Data Science" which starts with:

> Data science incorporates varying elements and builds on techniques
>   and theories from many fields, including mathematics, statistics, data
>   engineering, pattern recognition and learning, advanced computing,
>   visualization, uncertainty modeling, data warehousing, and high
>   performance computing with the goal of extracting meaning from data
>   and creating data products. Data science is a novel term that is often
>   used interchangeably with competitive intelligence or business
>   analytics, although it is becoming more common. Data science seeks to
>   use all available and relevant data to effectively tell a story that
>   can be easily understood by non-practitioners.

This would be under **IT** as it is about creating the system to report the data in a meaningful way.